# How can I add horizontal in between multiple <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following code and I want to add some more horizontal space in between the table data. Cellpadding doesn't work because it adds space both horizontally and vertically.

Here's my code:

```html
<table style="width: 745px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 16px;">
<tr>
<td width="25%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color:#D5D5D5;">
  <strong>Parking:</strong> None 
  </td>
  <td width="25%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color:#D5D5D5;">
  <strong>Floor Cover:</strong> Carpet 
  </td>
  <td width="25%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color:#D5D5D5;">
  <strong>Extra Field:</strong> None 
  </td>
    <td width="25%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color:#D5D5D5;">
  <strong>Extra Field:</strong> None 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="25%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color:#D5D5D5;"><strong>Fencing:</strong> None </td>
  <td width="25%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color:#D5D5D5;"><strong>Security:</strong> None</td>
  <td width="25%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color:#D5D5D5;"><strong>Pool:</strong> None </td>
    <td width="25%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; border-bottom-color:#D5D5D5;"><strong>Topography:</strong> None </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tables are just for data reporting. Use a layout using divs instead. Also note that inline styiling is a bad practice and should be replaced by a CSS stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.space {
  padding-top: 20px ;
  padding-bottom: 20px ;
  border-bottom: 1px solid; 
  border-bottom-color: #D5D5D5;
}
```

```html
<table  style="width: 745px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 16px;">
<tr  >
<td class="space" width="25%" >
  <strong>Parking:</strong> None 
  </td>
  <td class="space" width="25%">
  <strong>Floor Cover:</strong> Carpet 
  </td>
  <td class="space" width="25%">
  <strong>Extra Field:</strong> None 
  </td>
    <td class="space" width="25%">
  <strong>Extra Field:</strong> None 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="space" width="25%"><strong>Fencing:</strong> None </td>
  <td class="space" width="25%"><strong>Security:</strong> None</td>
  <td class="space" width="25%"><strong>Pool:</strong> None </td>
    <td class="space" width="25%"><strong>Topography:</strong> None </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It seems that it adds space below and above while keeping left & right intact.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the left and right spacing just remove the table width

Answer (score 0):

You can use [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) property in CSS. Go through [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/me4nkqLf/4/) to see this

HTML Code -

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <strong>Parking:</strong> None
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Floor Cover:</strong> Carpet
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Extra Field:</strong> None
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Extra Field:</strong> None
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Fencing:</strong> None </td>
    <td><strong>Security:</strong> None</td>
    <td><strong>Pool:</strong> None </td>
    <td><strong>Topography:</strong> None </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS Code -

```
.table {
  width: 745px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.table td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #D5D5D5;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

Also, try to avoid write inline CSS. Hope it helps you.